# CKEditor - get changed content and surrounding HTML tags

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I am writing my own plugin for Drupal. I checked the following code in the API for the change events:

```
  editor.on('change', function (evt) {
    console.log(this.getData());
  });
```

With it, I can see all the data in my editor when changed. I have my content structured with custom HTML tags (which have some data attributes). My question is, if the user writes some content, how can I get the closest tags - and therefore add a data attribute that it has been changed?

I'd also need some kind of timer/delay, to not trigger that on every keystroke, I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown is jQuery code. You've made a function that fires on change event on editor. It will fire every time user changes something in editor. To avoid this you can make something like this:

add an global variable at parent scope (before your function):

```
var editorTimer = null;
```

then change your function to:

```
if (editorTimer.length) {
    clearTimeout(editorTimer);
}
editorTimer = setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(this.getData());
}, 1000);
```

It will clear last timer and then wait 1000ms (1s) after each change to fire the function inside.
If user won't change anything for 1s the function will be called.

Now - you need to prepare your function and change the console.log() to something that works. To find tags use jQuery selectors:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

like .closest() or .parents() or .find() it depends what you are willing to do.

Comment: Thanks. I used getSelection() and getRanges() after that, then I set the attribute to the parent element.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please up vote it and mark as answered.